# editing files at the same time when cron automatically runs backup

Tags: cron, backup

I heard that it is a good idea to schedule backup in crontab file.

I also head that it is bad to edit files while they are backed up.

It may happen that cron stats to backup a directory while I am still editing some files in the directory. 
What shall I do to prevent or deal with the above situation?

Can I be notified a few minutes before cron starts to run back up, so that I can stop editing?
Can I be notified when backup scheduled by cron finishes, so that I can resume editing?

Comment: What editors do you use? Unless you use one that truncates the original file when writing (such as `ed` or the original `vi`), or use `dd` to do the backup, there's little to worry about.

Comment: emacs for text files, and Adobe Pro or PDFXChange for pdf files, ....  Will they be problems? @MarkPlotnick.  What do you mean by "truncates the original file"? Why is `dd`  a problem?

Comment: What software are you using to do backups?

Comment: rsync ..................... @Mark

Comment: The easiest way is to avoid the problem by scheduling backup at a time when you won't be working on the files. Alternatively consider a filesystem that supports snapshots such as btrfs or use LVM; but both of these will require restructuring your existing setup.

Comment: @gogoud: Can I be notified when cron starts to back up, so that I can stop editing.

Comment: see post [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1988960) on how to use notify-send from crontab to do a pop-up. Suggest you have a crontab line something like: `export DISPLAY=:0 && notify-send "Backup warning" "Backup is about to begin, get ready..." -t 60000; sleep 2m; rsync...`. Info about notify-send [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411620) - you might need to install notify-osd package first (if using debian-derived distro).

Comment: Thanks. [My script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197755/schedule-backup-with-notification#) can backup, but the notifications aren't right. Could you help to take a look? @gogoud