# Schedule backup with notification?

Tags: bash, cron, backup, notifications

[To avoid editing files at the same time of backup scheduled by cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197517/editing-files-at-the-same-time-when-cron-automatically-runs-backup), I figure out a way:

- Before backup, send a desktop notification such as `notify-send -t 0 "Ready for backup"`, to let me prepare (save my editing to files, and plug in external hard drive as backup destination), and when I am ready, I will click okay on the notification, and backup starts.
- Once backup finishes, optionally notify me with backup command's exit value and time taken for backup, so I can resume editing.

How can I do that in bash and Ubuntu?
This contains a smaller problem:
[how to schedule desktop notification in cron?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197751/my-cron-job-doesnt-run)

Feel free if you have a better way to achieve my goal at the beginning.

**My attempt.**

I added `* * * * * /home/t/mybackup.sh` to `crontab -e`, 
where I wrote a bash script `/home/t/mybackup.sh` wrapping backup and notifications:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                          
export DISPLAY=:0
/usr/bin/notify-send -t 0 "Ready for backup?" &&
    dest=/tmp/`date +%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S`&&
    mkdir -p "$dest" &&
    timetake=`time /usr/bin/rsync -a /home/t/program_files/dir/ "$dest"/  2>"$dest"/rsync-errors`; exitvalue=`echo $?`
/usr/bin/notify-send -t 0 "Finished backup!" "time taken: " $timetake " exit value:" $exitvalue
```

It has the following problems:

- I want to make the first notification "Ready for backup?" wait for my response before backup. i.e. Ideally, if I click "OK", then it can continue to backup. If I click "Cancel", then it shouldn't run backup and the following commands in the script.

  But in my current script, the first `notify-send` doesn't wait for my response and continue to backup.

  Even if I could make it wait for my response, I don't know how to code in my script to pick up my response of whether I click "OK" or "Cancel".
- the second `notify-send` for "Finished backup! ..." doesn't appear after backup finishes.

Comment: If your fileystems - or at least your important one(s) - are on LVM then `rsnapshot` can be configured to run an `rsync` backup from an LVM snapshot.

Comment: not on LVM. so I will stop changing anything during backup.

Comment: If you have to be sitting there to click the ok button anyhow, then why bother with scheduling?  Just run the backup manually.

Comment: because I often forget. @psusi